# Symfony2 get to the access_control parameters located in the security.yml

Tags: php, security, symfony, service, access-control

I'm trying to get the access_control parameters which are located in my security.yml as an array in my custom service.

Just like with getting the role_hierarchy parameters I thought it would work with the following code:

```php
$accessParameters = $this->container->getParameter('security.access_control');
```

Unfortunately this was not the case. Can someone tell how to get the parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to get the `access_control` parameter from  the container.
This is because this parameter is [only used](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L81) to create [request matchers](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L172) which will be registered as [AccessMap](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/AccessMap.php) later given in the [AccessListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php), and then are left over without registering it into the container.

You can try something hacky to get these matchers back by getting them like

```
$context  = $this->get("security.firewall.map.context.main")->getContext();
$listener = $context[0][5];
// Do reflection on "map" private member
```

But this is kind of an ugly solution.

Another way I can see on how to get them is to parse again the security file

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$file   = sprintf("%s/config/security.yml", $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir'));
$parsed = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));

$access = $parsed['security']['access_control'];
```

If you want to register this configuration into a service, you can do something like

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    acme.config_provider:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\ConfigProvider
        arguments:
            - "%kernel.root_dir%"
    acme.my_service:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\MyService
        arguments:
            - "@acme.config_provider"
```

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\ConfigProvider**</kbd>

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

class ConfigProvider
{
    protected $rootDir;

    public function __construct($rootDir)
    {
        $this->rootDir = $rootDir;
    }

    public function getConfiguration()
    {
        $file = sprintf(
            "%s/config/security.yml",
            $this->rootDir
        );
        $parsed = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));

        return $parsed['security']['access_control'];
    }
}
```

<kbd>**Acme\FooBundle\MyService**</kbd>

```
class MyService
{
    protected $provider;

    public function __construct(ConfigProvider $provider)
    {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }

    public function doAction()
    {
        $access = $this->provider->getConfiguration();

        foreach ($access as $line) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it aint pretty, it's still the best option if the parameters can't be obtained with the container.

Comment: Note that it may not be accurate if you clear the cache in prod env then modify the file without re-clearing the cache.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 0):

Necro, but still relevant. This is an improvement on Touki's answer above, where we don't reparse the access_control definitions, but rather use the already configured security token, firewall and access map to work out the answer.

<kbd>**.../services.yml**</kbd>

```
...

My\Application\AuthenticationBundle\Security\AccessControlHelper:
    class: My\Application\AuthenticationBundle\Security\AccessControlHelper
    arguments:
        $securityContext: "@security.context"
        $firewall: '@security.firewall.map'
        $accessDecisionManager: '@security.access.decision_manager'
        $accessMap: '@security.access_map'

...
```

<kbd>**src/My/Application/AuthenticationBundle/Security/AccessControlHelper.php**</kbd>

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace My\Application\AuthenticationBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessMapInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\FirewallMapInterface;

class AccessControlHelper
{
    /**
     * @var SecurityContextInterface
     */
    protected $securityContext;

    /**
     * @var FirewallMapInterface
     */
    protected $firewallMap;

    /**
     * @var AccessDecisionManagerInterface
     */
    protected $accessDecisionManager;

    /**
     * @var AccessMapInterface
     */
    protected $accessMap;

    public function __construct(
        SecurityContextInterface $securityContext,
        FirewallMapInterface $firewallMap,
        AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager,
        AccessMapInterface $accessMap
    )
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->firewallMap = $firewallMap;
        $this->accessDecisionManager = $accessDecisionManager;
        $this->accessMap = $accessMap;
    }

    public function isRequestAccessible(Request $request): bool
    {
        $token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
        if (!$token || false == $token->isAuthenticated()) {
            return false;
        }

        list($listeners) = $this->firewallMap->getListeners($request);
        if ($listeners) {
            foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
                if ($listener instanceof AccessListener) {
                    /**
                     * Logic here is much inspired by the AccessListener->handle(...) method.
                     */
                    list($attributes) = $this->accessMap->getPatterns($request);

                    if (null === $attributes) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    return boolval($this->accessDecisionManager->decide($token, $attributes, $request));
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function isUriAccessible(string $uri)
    {
        return $this->isRequestAccessible(Request::create($uri));
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```php
use My\Application\AuthenticationBundle\Security\AccessControlHelper;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$container = ...; // @var ContainerInterface

$accessControlHelper = $container->get(AccessControlHelper::class);
$accessControlHelper->isRequestAccessible(new Request("/foo"));
$accessControlHelper->isUriAccessible("/foo");
```