# Symfony 2 Security: Get page roles

Tags: php, security, symfony, access-control

I have my access_control defined in security.ylm.
Is it possible to get the current page roles in my code (without parsing the ylm file 'by hand') ?

Thanks

Comment: I dont get these downvotes without comments! Im I stupid? Ok, prove it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 get to the access\_control parameters located in the security.yml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831114/symfony2-get-to-the-access-control-parameters-located-in-the-security-yml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its duplicate of : [Symfony2 get to the access_control parameters located in the security.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831114/symfony2-get-to-the-access-control-parameters-located-in-the-security-yml?rq=1)

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$file   = sprintf("%s/config/security.yml", $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir'));
$parsed = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));

$access = $parsed['security']['access_control'];
```